# how to extend apache spark api?

Tags: apache-spark

i've been tasked with figuring out how to extend spark's api to include some custom hooks for another program like iPython Notebook to latch on to. I've already gone through the [quick start guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html), [the cluster mode overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html), the [submitting applications doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298192/how-to-run-a-spark-java-program/22306203#22306203). Everything I'm seeing indicates that, to get something to run in Spark, you need to use

> spark-submit

to make it happen. As such I whipped up some code that, visa vis spark, pulled the first ten rows of test data out of an accumulo table I created. My team lead, however, is telling me to modify spark itself. Is this the preferred way to accomplish the task I described? If so, why? What's the value proposition?

Comment: really? drive by down vote? com'on man, that's downright cowardly. is it really that difficult to read the question and post a thoughtful criticism?

Comment: Please elaborate on "custom hooks": what are you trying to achieve (and no i did not downvote: your question is a reasonable start). Specifically - are there additional features required by SqlContext or RDD? Or can you combine the existing ones to achieve your needs?

Comment: @javadba - thx for the reply - and it would've been totally cool if you downvoted! I'm just getting very frustrated as of late with SO's policy of allowing anonymous drive-by voting. we're endeavoring to create a link between spark and accumulo such that something like Notebook can sit atop spark and access the accumulo data, use spark to perform map reduce operations, etc. as to what EXACTLY is required - on that point I haven't received specifics from my lead. he did, however, point me to geomesa and told me to read their code, which I'm doing now.

Comment: I went ahead and created a general answer below - but uncertain to what extent it may be helpful.  I do dislike drive by downvotes as well (and upvoted your question after thinking a bit about it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No details have been provided about what types of operations your application requires so an answer here will need to remain general in nature.

The question of extending spark itself may come down to:

> Can I achieve the needs of the application by leveraging the existing
>   methods within Spark(/SQL/Hive/Streaming)Context and RDD
>   (/SchemaRDD/DStream/..)

additional choices:

> Is it possible to embed the required functionality inside the
>   transformation methods of RDD's - either by custom code or by invoking
>   third party libraries.

The likely distinguishing factors here would be if the existing data access and shuffle/distribution structures support your needs.  When it comes to data tranformations - in most cases you should be able to embed the required logic within the methods of RDD.

So:

```
case class InputRecord(..)
case class OutputRecord(..)
def myTranformationLogic(inputRec: InputRecord) : OutputRecord = {
  // put your biz rules/transforms here
  (return) outputRec
}
val myData = sc.textFile(<hdfs path>).map{ l => InputRecord.fromInputLine(l)}
val outputData = myData.map(myTransformationLogic)
outputData.saveAsTextFile(<hdfs path>)
```

Comment: let's assume for the sake of argument that there's something my lead has in mind that isn't provided in the stock version of Spark. what, in your estimation, is the benefit of extending spark vs using spark-submit? also, here is a link for the geomesa code I'm cruising through as it's apparently extends spark to make its magic happen

Comment: The preferred approach would clearly be to write code that lives within the transformation steps of stock Spark RDD's (and thus via spark-submit).  This is not about performance but about effort and maintainability.

Comment: To expand: you would not change the source code of your web server by first choice .. instead add code to a servlet to do what you need.

Comment: that is an excellent question! unfortunately i don't have an answer right now. i'm not familiar yet with the entire technology stack, and thus, not completely clear on the reasoning behind the some of the architectural decisions. as i understand you, creating a scala module that can be submitted to spark as an indefinitely running process won't create any significant performance issues - correct?